# Is there any cheap/free dashboard app that have user friendly editor?

Tags: reporting, business-intelligence, dashboard

I'm looking for options that allow me to start small in term of license commitments. Open source will not be a problem.

What we need is a dashboard reporting application that can have interactive components (user can filter or drill down by interacting with the charts, and those kind of fancy stuff), and also have a **WYSIWYG editor** that allow **non-technical users** to create and modify dashboards. Basically something like [inetsoft dashboard](http://www.inetsoft.com/evaluate/dashboard_software_reviews/).

Is there such thing at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of open source, [Pentaho BI Suite](http://www.pentaho.com/) is probably the best open source BI suite I've come across and they have the Pentaho Dashboard Designer which is aimed at the power user (so non tech users can use it).

I've deployed Pentaho in several medium organisations and have had power users designing reports and dashboards through the implementation period with little troubles (providing some initial training is given).

Depending on the format and size of your DWH, you might also find that Excel (assuming you already have licenses) can provide pretty decent drag-and-drop dashboards as well.

Comment: I did some research on Pentaho a couple of months ago, and I believe the user-friendly dashboard tools are limited to the paid version.  I could be wrong, someone please correct me if the free version does support WYSIWYG dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for SaaS or On-premise software? You would recommend some BI tool for you. I would not recommend Excel for such kind of reporting due to very limited sharing/dataset possibilities.

Peter